# No audio while tab casting with Chromecast and Chromium

Tags: sound, chromium, chromecast

I just got my Chromecast and it rocks, but I can't seem to get it to play audio while tab-casting from Chromium.  When using the direct cast options like youtube it works fine, and when I use other computers it also works fine, but on this laptop running Ubuntu and Chromium I get no audio.  Kind of sucks because I'm really hoping to use spotify's web client to stream spotify to my living room, which was one of the main reasons I got Chromecast in the first place.

Has anyone else come across this problem?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Same problem. Chromium on Ubuntu 13.10. Chromecast extension will send video, but not audio.

Comment: currently have same problem

Comment: Does it work on a Windows/Mac?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it's related with the HDMI port on the TV. I had this problem and at first I solved it turning off my home theater, so that the audio would come from the TV's speakers. Then, after reading [this post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromecast/_mTGyEbnTqQ) I tried using the HDMI extender and now I get the sound from my home theater.
I hope it helps.