# Chromecast - tab casting problem

Tags: chromium, chromecast

Just got Chromecast and it is set up, working successfully for YouTube and all the other "optimized" best supported stuff. But not the tab cast.

When I attempt to use it I get the message `Lost Connection to Device - Please check that your device is online`. 
I'm not exactly sure where to start looking into this. This is really holding me up, because streaming local movies was/is my main motivation for getting ChromeCast and it seems that running a media server and playing in my own browser is the way to go, at least until we get support for VLC or UPnP streams. So frustrating that videos I don't "have" can be played, but those that I do "have" can't be!

Any ideas? Even suggestion towards what direction to further explore would be helpful.

---

Sorry if the question shows lack of research, but I am kind of at a loss. Have googled it a little but as of yet failed to find anyone with a similar problem. Other streams work so the iptables thing described here: [How can I use Chromecast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/324236/how-can-i-use-chromecast) doesn't seem to be the issue. The tab caster doesn't work at all and reports "Lost connection to device" so my problem seems different from purely audio issues like this: [No audio while tab casting with Chromecast and Chromium](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360111/no-audio-while-tab-casting-with-chromecast-and-chromium)

I am running Chromium 31.0.1650.63 Ubuntu 12.04 and I just got Google Cast (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-cast/boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd?hl=en) a few days ago so that's gotta be current.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem specific to a few users, tab casting isn't currently supported with Linux. I guess they are still working out the kinks or something. The only workaround that I've found to work is to just use a windows VM, just make sure to set your network settings in whatever VM you use to bridged, else it won't detect the chromecast.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily stream local video files using Chrome and maybe chromium by installing this extension 
WWW.GETVIDEOSTREAM.COM

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/videostream-for-google-ch/cnciopoikihiagdjbjpnocolokfelagl